# How to paste data into next empty cell to the right?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2, row number 9 with one condition. The data should be inserted to the next empty cell to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure that is a bit more general than @FahmiYogyas question.
Assume the source range is a named range of one or more cells (here `NamedRange1`) and the top left cell of the destination is a second named range (here `NamedRange2`).

```
Option Explicit
'
' start this as example
'
Sub test1()
    copyData Range("NamedRange1"), Range("NamedRange2")
End Sub

'
'
'
Sub copyData(sourceRange As Range, destinationRange As Range)
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim columnOffset As Long
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim isFirst As Boolean
    '
    ' increase the column offset until the first destination cell is empty
    '
    Do While Not IsEmpty(destinationRange.Offset(0, columnOffset))
        columnOffset = columnOffset + 1
    Loop

    isFirst = True
    '
    ' now get the value of the source cells
    ' and insert it at the destination position
    ' offset is used to allow for arbitrary source ranges
    For Each myCell In sourceRange
        If isFirst Then
            Set firstCell = myCell
            isFirst = False
        End If

        destinationRange.Offset(myCell.Row - firstCell.Row, myCell.Column - firstCell.Column + columnOffset).Value = myCell.Value
    Next

End Sub
```